# In search of a word for a specific moment of time

Tags: single-word-requests

In search of a word for a specific moment of time or feeling…

When you have worked towards a goal for a really long time and you have finally reached it. But that one moment of self reflection before the leap.

Examples:

1. Getting into college and the pause you make to take a deep breath before opening the door for orientation.
2. The pause before the curtains open on opening night of your first performance.

I have been searching for this word for nearly a decade and I don’t know if it exists but I know this feeling well and would appreciate any help to find it in any language.

Comment: There are obvious hypernyms like 'apprehensive', Nelson, but I'm sure you're after something far more specific. There are suitable expressions (eg 'on the brink of ... [eg "a sea change"]') if not a single word, but you'd have to select 'phrase requests' as an additional tag to allow these.

Comment: What's an example of a sentence where you'd use this word?

Comment: I’d call it anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives that are suitable here are **pregnant** and **momentous**:

> *pregnant* [adjective]
>
> ...
>
> 3: rich in significance or implication
>
> - *the pregnant phrases of the Bible* —Edmund Wilson
> - *a pregnant pause*
>
> 4: having possibilities of development or consequence : involving important issues : *momentous*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pregnant)]

> *pregnant*
>
> ...
>
> 2 [formal]: filled with meaning or emotion because of what is going to
> happen or be said
>
> - *There was a pregnant pause/silence before the winner was announced*.
>
> — often + with
>
> - *The moment was pregnant with excitement*.

[[Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/pregnant)]

An example from [Liverpool School of Tropical Medicine](https://www.lstmed.ac.uk/news-events/seminars-and-lectures/delivery-research-in-global-health-a-pregnant-moment) showing this sense is

> - *Delivery research in global health: a pregnant moment?*

And two appropriate examples from Collins:

> - *a silence pregnant with suspense*
> - *a pregnant moment in the history of the world*

.....................

> *momentous*
>
> Momentous describes an important event or moment in time. It is used for a time of great consequence or for a major
> accomplishment, and is almost always reserved for good things.

[[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/momentous)]

'Momentous' is not as close a fit here, as it need not be anticipatory.